# Get Alembic Frame range from imported file via python

Tags: python, alembic

Is it possible to use python to get the frame range stored in an imported alembic file? I assume it's on the cache datablock but I can't see anything that would yield this information.

many thanks

Comment: do you have some answer to this question?

Comment: Only thing I could think of was save the current timeline range, then grab this again post import as Blender sets the timeline to what is in the imported file. You can then restore the original range and have the Alembic range as a variable